# Exporting data to Access using VBA (looping issue)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I've created 2 subs which connect to an open Access database (MasterFile_January2021.accdb) and exports the data to this database.

At the moment, it seems to go into an endless loop of exporting the data from Monthly Reporting Tool - 600k+ rows were exported before it crashed compared to 250k expected rows (and I could find duplicates when there were not in the original file).

```
Sub ExportData()

    Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String, fileName As String
    Dim strTable As String
    Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean
    
    
    blnHasFieldNames = True
    
    strPath = "Z:\Danny Tool Test Folder\"
    
    strTable = "tblDatabase"
    
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "Monthly Reporting Tool.xlsm")
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
    
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: So would you suggest removing the 'Do While' loop and leaving the rest as is?

Comment: Worked. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code calls `TransferSpreadsheet` from within an infinite loop.  The loop never terminates because `strFile` never changes, so `Len(strFile) > 0` is always true.

However you want to import the Excel data once, so don't call `TransferSpreadsheet` in a loop.

```vb
strFile = Dir(strPath & "Monthly Reporting Tool.xlsm")
'Do While Len(strFile) > 0 '*** disable or remove this line ***'
strPathFile = strPath & strFile
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
    strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
'Loop '*** disable or remove this line ***'
```